# Forwarded Types in Microsoft Unity

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, unity-container

How to use single component for multiple services in Unity Framework?

In Windsor it is configured in the following way:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Component.For<Service1, Service2>()
                            .ImplementedBy<Component>());

var service1 = container.Resolve<Service1>();
var service2 = container.Resolve<Service2>();
```

The idea with forwarded types is that if the component is a singleton `service1` and `service2` **are the same instance**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This test passes:

```
[Fact]
public void ContainerCorrectlyForwards()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IService1, MyComponent>(
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IService2, MyComponent>(
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

    var service1 = container.Resolve<IService1>();
    var service2 = container.Resolve<IService2>();

    Assert.Same(service1, service2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But did you know that test will pass even if you remove ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() for IService1 or IService2? Who decided that ContainerControlled will override Transient lifetime (for components with the same names - default name in our case)?

Comment: That is indeed surprising. I have no good explanation for that. In fact, I'd be tempted to log that as a bug...

Comment: With Unity 1.2 that test fails without ContainerControlledLifetimeManager

Comment: ... and fails with Unity 2.0, too, without ContainerControlledLifetimeManager.

Comment: @onof: Yes, but Rationalle's point was that if you remove only *one of them* it still succeeds. I have verified this for Unity 2, but not 1.2.

Comment: ahh.. sorry. Anyway it succeeds in 1.2 too. weird

Comment: There is a reason for this behavior. It's up to you to decide if it's a good reason. :-) The lifetime manager and injection members are applied to the IMPLEMENTATION type. Since you're using the same implemementation type, the last one wins. However, if you don't specify a lifetime manager, it doesn't supply a new Transient one - instead one springs into existence the first time you request the type and there isn't one specified.

Comment: (Ran out of room). Anyway, the code above is equivalent to:  container.RegisterType<IService1, MyComponent>().RegisterType<IService2,MyComponent>().RegisterType<MyComponent>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

Comment: Chris, your comment finally explained the reason of this behavior. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't: you have to register each service with the same mapped component:

```
container.RegisterType<Service1, Component>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
         .RegisterType<Service2, Component>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
```

Comment: Does it really do forwarded types? Or registers two separate components. See updated question.

Comment: This answer results in two different instances when you resolve Service1 and Service2 because the default lifetime in Unity is Transient.

Comment: Yes it resulted in two different instances. Singleton lifetime needed